# Formatter URL Javascript error

Tags: javascript, asp.net, url

I am using below code to open the new window from server side

```
 string UserId = "99798";
    string url = "http://www.XYZ.com?Id='"+UserId+"&MatId=12";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<script>");
    sb.Append("window.open("+url+", 'my_App', '');");
    sb.Append("</scri");
    sb.Append("pt>");
    Page.RegisterStartupScript("test", sb.ToString());
```

But it is giving me javascript error

> Expected ')'

But everything is working fine when URL = "http://www.google.com";

What is the error? How can I resolve this

Comment: What does the resulting JavaScript look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string UserId = "99798";
    string url = "http://www.XYZ.com?Id="+UserId+"&MatId=12";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<script>");
    sb.Append("window.open('"+url+"', 'my_App', '');");
    sb.Append("</scri");
    sb.Append("pt>");
    Page.RegisterStartupScript("test", sb.ToString());
```

Comment: And generally it's useful to tell what is wrong with the OP's code, now he can simply copy-paste your code without learning anything.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to create a querystring after `http://www.XYZ.com` query string format is

```
url?key1=value1&key2=value2...&keyn=valuen
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It was the typo. I am sorry for that. :-( I am little tense you can check here why .. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/72374/working-on-weekends/72388#72388

Comment: ahaha i see.Working on weekends sucks really. Good luck on that /:

Answer (score 0):

You should also use (though it isn't the problem, it is a best practice)

```
sb.Append("<script type='text/javascript'>");
```